# Extjs4 MVC. Retain Prevoius View with all the Form Data on Back Button

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs

I have a 1 app with 8 veiws, 8 controllers for each view with multiple stores and models.

scenario : Navigate from first view to second view. on the second view i will provide a back button which should navigate to previous screen(first view) with all form data retained.

issue here is, on click of back button i am calling the controller 1 to bring the view 1 to front and all data which was selected has got lost.

is there any way i can retain those data on the view1.?????????

i donot wat to use a single controller to handle all 8 views as this would be a burden on a single controller file.

kindly help us out here

Thanks,
Punith

Answer (score 0):

nope, not actually.
my post was wrong above.

The instance of the previuos view is not getting destroyed. to render a already instatiated view, we just need to show the previous panel/container. so the data present is never lost until a new instance of this view is created.

Still new to extjs. if anyone finds it to expalin better.. please put it.

thanks
Punith